# symfony application doesn't work after installing laravel

Tags: laravel, symfony

I'm currently learning web development.
For the moment I have only used symfony to build my projects.
I just installed laravel for another project and now my symfony application doesn't work when displayed on the web page (there normally would be bootstrap, javascript, images - I'm using webpack encore)

[image: it looks like this]

I checked the DB - there is no problem.
I checked the routes and there is no problem either.
I don't really know what to check

I talked to a teacher of mine and he told me there could be a change of symfony CLI (as laravel is based on symfony) or a conflict of that kind but I'm still lost - that is why I need your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have to build your style. Run `npm run dev`or  `yarn dev` to build and copy the assets to your public build directory.